# MySQL PHP Allow User to Select From a Choice of Queries

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

On a web-page that will display tables/views from my MySQL database, I want the user to be able to select from a choice of different tables/views to look at. In other words, I want the user to be able to click a button or choose from a drop-down that will display a new table/view based upon their selection, similar to switching tabs in an excel sheet. If the user chooses a new table, the page will be updated with that tables data.

For Example:
(TWO TABLES FROM DATABASE)

```
CUSTOMERS
|---------------------|------------------|
|        Name         |        ID        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        Jane         |        34        |
|---------------------|------------------|

ORDERS
|---------------------|------------------|
|        Order        |        Part #    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        5354         |        75        |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

**User clicks orders button** (Only orders table is displayed)

```
ORDERS
|---------------------|------------------|
|        Order        |        Part #    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        5354         |        75        |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

**User then clicks customers button** (Only customers table is displayed)

```
CUSTOMERS
|---------------------|------------------|
|        Name         |        ID        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        Jane         |        34        |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

My thought is that you would need to have an array of queries, and an array of different tables that would match each query. Right now, I am only able to display one query result, and am not sure how to implement the method of selection (button, dropdown, etc), or how to update the page with a new query result.

Here is my current code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Database</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        table{
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 100%;
            font-family: monospace;
            font-size: 25px;
            text-align: left;
            padding: 15px;
        }
        th{
            background-color: #1E90FF;
            color: black;
            border: 1px solid black;
            padding: 15px;
            text-align: center;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #f2f2f2}
        tr{
            border: 1px solid black;
            padding: 15px;
        }
        td{
            border: 1px solid black;
            padding: 15px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>ID</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
            $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "mydb");
            if ($conn-> connect_error){
                die("Connection failed:".$conn-> connect_error);
            }

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM mydb.customers";
            $result = $conn-> query($sql);

            if($result-> num_rows > 0){
                while($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()){
                    echo "<tr<><td>".$row["Name"]."</td><td>".$row["ID"]."</td></tr>";
                }
                echo "</table>";
            }else{
                echo "0 result";
            }
            $conn-> close();
        ?>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because your tables have different column names, I suggest you create a separate page for each table like above and load them with <iframe> on your third page on a click of a button. EDIT: There are many ways to do this but this a basic way that I think may help you understand the flow better.

Comment: @SaydFuad Good idea, I hadn't thought of this. This solves the different tables issue, however I would ultimately like to add a filtering option to each table as well, so in the end I would need to update with a new query anyways. For instance: We have 10,000 records with 500 different IDs, so the user could type in one customer ID and the results would be filtered down to just those records. Thanks for the input!

Comment: Let say your link will be htt://example.com/customers  then just do HTTP://example.com/customers?id=123 then on your customer page where you do the database thing do $customer_id = $_GET['id'] then use that to filter that data